# ¿Cómo bloquear la ejecución hasta obtener una respuesta? (Modal YES, NO, CANCEL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal, messagebox

Estaba planteandome el hacer un modal para que haga las veces de "confirm()" pero con tres botones tipo Yes, No, Cancel. El caso es que llegué a un punto en el que me di cuenta de que necesito bloquear toda la ejecución del programa hasta obtener una respuesta del usuario. Es decir, si este es mi modal (a medio hacer):

```
function dialog(Header,text, btn1,btn2,btn3)
{
    this.value="";
    function onClick(value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }

    var txt = "";
    txt += '<div class="container2">';

    txt += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog3buttons">Open Modal</button>`';

     // <!-- Modal -->
    txt += '<div class="modal fade" id="dialog3buttons" role="dialog">';
    txt += '<div class="modal-dialog">';

    //    <!-- Modal content-->
    txt += '<div class="modal-content">';
    txt += '<div class="modal-header">';

    txt +=  '<h4 class="modal-title">'+Header+'</h4>';
    txt += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>';


    txt +=  '</div>';
    txt +=      '<div class="modal-body">';
    txt +=          '<p>'+text+'</p>';
    txt +=      '</div>'
    txt +=      '<div class="modal-footer">';
    txt +=        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="onClick('+btn1+')">'+btn1+'</button>';
    txt +=        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="onClick('+btn2+')">'+btn2+'</button>';
    txt +=        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="onClick('+btn3+')">'+btn3+'</button>';
    txt +=      '</div>';
    txt +=    '</div>';

    txt +=  '</div>';
    txt +=   '</div>';

    txt +=   '</div>';



    $('#padre').append(txt);
    return this.value;
}

result = dialog("Advertencia","¿Desa hacer tal cosa...?", "yes","no","cancel");
alert(result);
```

Siempre obtengo un resultado incorrecto pues la ejecución del programa llega al "alert()" antes de que el usuario tenga tiempo a apretar alguno de los botones.

¿Alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: Deberías realizar un if antes que muestre el `alert`. La lógica podría ser que dependiendo lo que devuelva la función **dialog** (bool, string, etc) mostrar o no el `alert`.

Comment: La función dialog debería devolver un string con valor ("yes", "no", "cancel")... pero siempre devuelve un string vacio ("") porque la ejecución no espera a que el usuario pulse un botón... es por eso que si pongo un if para checkear lo que tu dices el alert nunca va a ser mostrado

Comment: Y si mueves el alert dentro de la función?

Comment: Pasaría exactamente lo mismo... y además el alert ese es solo para hacer un test y comprobar los resultados, al final debe ser eliminado... de hecho el objetivo de hacer este modal es precisamente para no usar  "alert" ni "confirm"... porque queda mas estético y porque el usuario puede deshabilitar las ventanas emergentes.

Comment: Estoy tratando de replicar tu código... una pregunta, no entiendo que es lo que debería hacer la línea del OnClick... podrías explicarme eso?

Comment: Si, mi intención es que cuando el usuario haga click en el botón... si por ejemplo pulsa "Yes" esa cadena se va a copiar en la variable de retorno (this.value)... Es decir que la función va a retornar "Yes"

Comment: Voy a tratar de replicar el código que tienes y encontrar el error, a todo esto.. no te sería mucho más fácil utilizar una librería de tipo SweetAlert que reinventar la rueda? Esa librería tiene justo lo que necesitas :)

Comment: Le daré un vistazo... aunque mientras menos librerias de terceros use mejor... ya me conozco lo quebraderos de cabeza que da el "upgrading" ... y la verdad no se si merecerá la pena (es un simple dialogo de tres botones)... seguro que se puede hacer en 50 lineas... pero falta el tema del bloqueo...

Comment: Por cierto... creo que el código no tiene ningún error.... al menos eso creo... simplente necesito bloquear la ejecución y esperar una respuesta.... si esto fuera programacion concurrente en C/C++ te hablaria de Threads, Semaphores, Waits.... pues estoy buscando una herramienta equivalente que me permita bloquear el hilo de ejecución hasta obtener una respuesta.

Comment: @IvánRodríguez En Javascript hay un único hilo en ejecución. Sencillamente no hay E/S bloqueante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese código debe ser asíncrono, ya que depende de un evento (el usuario seleccionando una opción). Una solución sencilla sería usar promesas:

```js
function dialog(header,text, btn1,btn2,btn3)
{
    $('#texto').html(text);
    $('#header').html(header);
    $('#btnOk').html(btn1);
    $('#btnNo').html(btn2);
    $('#btnCan').html(btn3);
    $('#popup').show();
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      //Añadimos un listener para una vez, por eso se usa one y no on
      $('#popup button').one('click',function () {
        $('#popup').hide();
        resolve($(this).html());
      });
    });  
}

$('#popupBtn').click(function() {
  
  let promise = dialog("Advertencia","¿Desea hacer tal cosa...?", "yes","no","cancel");
  promise.then(respuesta => {
  //dentro de esta función es donde existe la respuesta
    console.log(respuesta);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="popupBtn">Abre popup</button>

<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
  <h3 id="header"></h3>
  <p id="texto"></p>
  <button id="btnOk"></button> <button id="btnNo"></button><button id="btnCan"></button>
</div>
```

Por otro lado, bloquear el hilo de ejecución en Javascript es siempre una mala idea, de hecho las llamadas síncronas provocan *warnings* en la consola, al igual que el código que consume demasiado tiempo en ejecutarse.

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta... lo mejor que he visto por el momento... voy a intentar usarlo en el modal a ver que tal va!! Muchas gracias @PabloLozano!!

Comment: Va de maravilla... me encantan estas promesas :-)  Muchas gracias otra vez!!